# Linear Algebra - Find inverse of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have this problem :

$$A =  \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 2 \end{array}\right) $$

1) Show that $A^3-5A^2+8A-4I=0$.

2) Using (1) To find $A^{-1}$.

I did (1) show that is correct, Usually to find inverse I use the Identity Matrix.

Anyhow for this problem, I thought of something like that :

$$A^3-5A^2+8A-4I=0 \implies  
\\A^3-5A^2+8A=4I \implies 
\\\frac{A^3-5A^2+8A}{4}=I \implies
\\\frac{A^3}{4}-\frac{5}{4}A^2+2A=I \implies
\\ A\left(\frac{A^2}{4}-\frac{5}{4}A+2I\right)=I$$

Then I think that : $$A^{-1}=\left(\frac{A^2}{4}-\frac{5}{4}A+2I\right)$$

I checked if $A^{-1}A=I$, but this is not the case.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: A word of caution: your equation (1) is missing an $I$, so it is not quite meaningful - it equates a sum of matrix powers to a scalar, 4. Anyhow, move the $4I$ over to one side and left or right multiply by $A^{-1}$

Comment: @user_of_math Edited add $I$, I moved $4I$ to one side look at what I did.

Comment: Why are you adding a scalar, 2, to a sum of matrix powers in the very last equation?

Comment: @user_of_math Edited, sorry about that where I study it's trival not add $I$ when discussing about matrices.

Comment: Note that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\displaystyle p(\lambda)=\lambda^3-5\lambda^2+8\lambda-4$. Therefore by Cayley-Hamilton theorem we know that $\displaystyle p(A)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 
$A^3 - 5 A^2 + 8A = 4I $

Left multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$. Use the fact that matrix multiplication is associative, and $A^{-1}A=I$,
$$
A^2 - 5A + 8I = 4A^{-1}
$$
which gives you an $A^{-1}$ of
$$
\frac{1}{4}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
-3 & 5 & -1 \\
-2 & 2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

You can now check that $A A^{-1}$ is indeed $I$.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I wonder if also my way is correct? since I don't get $AA^{-1}=I$ my way.

Comment: @JaVaPG Compare our expressions for $A^{-1}$ - they are really the same. You should check your work to find your mistake.